# How to handle error with devm_regulator_get

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to handle the case when `devm_regulator_get` can't find a matching regulator. I'm programming on kernel 4.9.30

From linux kernel sources we can see the following description [ [drivers/regulator/devres.c](http:///**%20%20*%20devm_regulator_get%20-%20Resource%20managed%20regulator_get()%20%20*%20@dev:%20device%20for%20regulator%20%22consumer%22%20%20*%20@id:%20Supply%20name%20or%20regulator%20ID.%20%20*%20%20*%20Managed%20regulator_get().%20Regulators%20returned%20from%20this%20function%20are%20%20*%20automatically%20regulator_put()%20on%20driver%20detach.%20See%20regulator_get()%20for%20more%20%20*%20information.%20%20*/%20struct%20regulator%20*devm_regulator_get(struct%20device%20*dev,%20const%20char%20*id)%20%7B%20%09return%20_devm_regulator_get(dev,%20id,%20NORMAL_GET);%20%7D%20EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(devm_regulator_get);) / [drivers/regulator/core.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.30/source/drivers/regulator/core.c#L1697) ]

**drivers/regulator/devres.c**

```
/**
 * devm_regulator_get - Resource managed regulator_get()
 * @dev: device for regulator "consumer"
 * @id: Supply name or regulator ID.
 *
 * Managed regulator_get(). Regulators returned from this function are
 * automatically regulator_put() on driver detach. See regulator_get() for more
 * information.
 */
struct regulator *devm_regulator_get(struct device *dev, const char *id)
{
    return _devm_regulator_get(dev, id, NORMAL_GET);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(devm_regulator_get);
```

**drivers/regulator/core.c**

```
/**
 * regulator_get - lookup and obtain a reference to a regulator.
 * @dev: device for regulator "consumer"
 * @id: Supply name or regulator ID.
 *
 * Returns a struct regulator corresponding to the regulator producer,
 * or IS_ERR() condition containing errno.
 *
 * Use of supply names configured via regulator_set_device_supply() is
 * strongly encouraged.  It is recommended that the supply name used
 * should match the name used for the supply and/or the relevant
 * device pins in the datasheet.
 */
struct regulator *regulator_get(struct device *dev, const char *id)
{
    return _regulator_get(dev, id, false, true);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(regulator_get);
```

Here is my code

```
struct regulator *power_regulator = devm_regulator_get(&pdev->dev, "zdfhkfgv");
if(IS_ERR(power_regulator))
{
    ERROR("Invalid power regulator\r\n");
    return -EINVAL;
}
```

However I'm never falling in the error case even if the regulator is not found.

Here is the kernel output :

```
# insmod mod.ko 
module : Init driver
module : Device allocated and initialized
module supply zdfhkfgv not found, using dummy regulator
module : device is not powered
[...]
```

So I can see that `devm_regulator_get` failed to find the regulator but I'm not falling into the error case. This is quite anoying because when the regulator isn't set I shall return. Instead of that the code continue running with a device which is not powered.

**What am I doing wrong here ?**

Comment: Nothing. The problem will arise AFAIU when you actually start using it, for example, change voltage, or enable it.

Comment: So there is no way to know if the regulator was found or not? That's weird 'coz the function noticed me that `module supply zdfhkfgv not found, using dummy regulator` so at least I should be able to know if I'am using a dummy regulator or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is devm_regulator_get_optional() you should use if you do not want to fall back on a dummy regulator.
It will then return -ENODEV instead.